# Multiple box plots in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the form of this table. There are two conditions: Treated and Untreated.

| Condition | ENSG | average raw counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Untreated | ENSG00000260456 | 1.190091e-05 |
| Treated | ENSG00000183570 | 2.935156e-05 |

I'm interested in making a box plot with the data in this format (i.e. red = treated, teal = untreated).

[desired_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROExi.png)

The code I have thus far makes a box plot by separating the x axis into bins, but I would like to have something that looks like the plot image above.

```
p <- joinSum %>%
  mutate( bin=cut_width(`sumcol1`, width=0.00075, boundary=0) ) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=bin, y=joinSum$avg_rep) ) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#69b3a2") +
  xlab("Bin")

print(p)
```

Here is an image of my current plot:

[current_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMGaZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was difficult to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) out of the data provided, but here is a potential solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble::tribble(
   ~Condition,             ~ENSG, ~average.raw.counts,
  "Untreated", "ENSG00000260456",        1.190091e-05,
    "Treated", "ENSG00000183570",        1.195156e-05,
  "Untreated", "ENSG00000260451",        1.290091e-05,
  "Treated", "ENSG00000183572",        1.295156e-05,
  "Untreated", "ENSG00000260454",        1.390091e-05,
  "Treated", "ENSG00000183575",        1.395156e-05,
  "Untreated", "ENSG00000260457",        1.110091e-05,
  "Treated", "ENSG00000183578",        1.115156e-05
  )
data %>% 
  mutate(bin = cut_width(average.raw.counts, width = 0.000002, boundary = 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = bin, y = average.raw.counts)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Condition)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#f60013", "#21fffe")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: example_1.png]